# PHP Mail & Ajax: Message does not contain any form data

Tags: php, ajax, email

I'm using jQuery's AJAX function to send a message from a contact form -

```
$('form button').click(function () {

    $("input").removeClass("error");
    $("textarea").removeClass("error");

    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (name == "" || name == "Name" || name == "Namn") {
        $("#name").addClass("error");
        $("#name").focus();
        return false;
    }

    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (email == "" || email == "Email" || email == "Epost") {
        $("#email").addClass('error');
        $("#email").focus();
        return false;
    }

    var message = $("#message").val();
    if (message == "") {
        $("#message").addClass('error');
        $("#message").focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Non-verifying fields
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();

    // Gather data
    var post = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;

    // Disable form
    var limit = document.forms[0].elements.length;
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        document.forms[0].elements[i].disabled = true;
    }

    // Send data
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form_handler.php",
        data: post,
        success: function () {
            $('div.contact form').animate({
                opacity: 0.25
            }, function () {
                $('div.contact div.confirm').fadeIn(200);
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            $('div.contact form').animate({
                opacity: 0.25
            }, function () {
                $('div.contact div.deny').fadeIn(200);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I know this is not the safest method considering I reveal the Mail file in my JS code but nevertheless I want this to work before I decide to try anything else. In my contact form I have the above fields (name, email, phone and message) and in "form_handler.php" the settings look like this -

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "staffan.estberg@gmail.com";
$subject = "Meddelande från x.se";
$body = "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
$body .= "Meddelande från $name:\n\n";
$body .= "$message\n\n";
$body .= "Avsändarens epost: $email\n";
$body .= "Avsändarens telefonnummer: $phone\n\n";
$body .= "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
?>
```

When I combine the scripts I manage to generate a message though it doesn't contain any form data. Have I missed out on something?

Comment: Did you try dumping `$_POST` to see if you even get the data?

Comment: I'm not very skilled with PHP -  Where should I put it?

Comment: at the very beginning, do a `var_dump($_POST); die();` this will output every value it recieves via post, and then stop the script.

Comment: I added your code to the form_handler.php file and as a result I don't get any messages sent, which should confirm that the file hasn't received the POST values.

Comment: What does it output? The `die();` call stops the script (and prevents sending the mail),not the lack of post data.

Comment: OK. I don't know how to see what it outputs? Since I'm not redirected to the file while submitting.
Applying the Mail script as an action in the form tag works 100%.

Comment: If you say it works without JS, the problem is in your javascript code. Most probably what @infamouse mentioned in his answer - use that method instead of manually building the query string, which is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll actually want to pass a JSON array as the data parameter instead of the GET-style string.

Something like:

```
post = { 'name' : name, ... }
```

Comment: If you mean switching to "var post = { 'name' : name, 'email' : email, 'phone' : phone, 'message' : message };" in the JS file it didn't help.

Comment: Then get Firebug open and look at the AJAX request.  The net tab has a really easy way to see what is being sent to your server.  If the data is getting to the server then figure out what's wrong with your PHP.

Comment: Not sure what to look for in the Net tab but I can't see any of the field values.
Think I'm going for another solution, this is just frustrating.

Comment: I believe he meant the console tab, which displays detailed information about every ajax request, when enabled.

Comment: In the Net tab you can see the outgoing request, a list of parameters sent, the headers, and the response.  What more could you possibly need?  If you put a var_dump of $_POST in the PHP file and examine the response in the Net tab you should get a complete picture here...

Comment: I think I know what you're refering to now. There's nothing displaying in the "Response" tab under the process for form_handler.php. I changed some variable names just to see how  errors display.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. You know, I switched back to Firefox today because Chrome kept bugging and I got lack of it (even though I favor the browser because it's slim and doesn't require much). So what happens - this form thing that I've been working on the entire evening proves to be a Firefox THING. It works perfect in Chrome and Safari... Am I frustrated? Somewhat. Am I confused? Yes. Why on Earth does it not work in Firefox? I mean, parts of the JavaScript do work (such as fetching the form_handler.php through ajax).

Comment: Can't debug from your computer but it could be the Content-type header your sending back is incorrect.  Frankly, you're not sending back any HTML so you probably don't need it anyways.